# Changing basis $V$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, linear-groups

If $V$ is a vector space on $\mathbb{C}$ with finite dimension $n$. Take two basis $B_{1}, B_{2}$ of $V$ and the relative isomorphisms $F_{B_{i}}:GL(V) \rightarrow GL(n)$. The question is if exists a $\psi$ authomorphism of $GL(n)$ as algebra such that $F_{B_{1}}\psi=F_{B_{2}}$

Comment: $F_{B_i}$ is itself a ring isomorphism, so you can just like $\psi:F_{B_2}\circ F_{B_1}^{-1}$, no? Also, the $\psi$ in your question should be on the other side of $F_{B_1}$ for the composition to make sense.

Comment: Yes, right... And they are all algebras morphisms